# Looking for a way to prompt a scheduled message with options for the user to start (or not) a long backup batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, vbscript, windows-11-v22h2, freefilesync

I'm looking for a way to use Task Scheduler to warn the user before starting a long backup batch by showing a message box that waits for user confirmation.

I was trying to use task scheduler to run a FreeFileSync batch but show a message box before it actualy starts the batch.
I have made different approaches to this, for example, I had two actions in the same task, the first would show the message box and the second would run the FFS batch. With this I noticed that the box appears and disappears before any interaction and then runs the FFS batch.
Now i'm trying to schedule a task that presents the message box with Yes or No, and only then the .vbs itself would open the FFS batch if the answer is Yes.
I have copied this code from somewhere online and changed it for my use case:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,Question,PathProgram
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
PathProgram = "C:\*path*\FULL_BACKUP.ffs_batch"
Question = Msgbox("Executar FULL BACKUP?",4096 + VbYesNO + VbQuestion, "FULL BACKUP")
If Question = VbYes Then
     ws.run DblQuote(PathProgram)
End If
Function DblQuote(Str)
     DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

The problem is that this way nothing happens. But if I double click this .vbs file everything works just fine.

So, what am I doing wrong in task shedule ??

These are the screen captures of all the tabs in the task:
I have repeated this test and nothing happened again. But if i click the .vbs directly, everything works just fine.

(My images are in portuguese but it is the same layout for everyone)

[The task and its schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/859OK.jpg)
[The time has passed and nothing happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyTEW.jpg)
[General settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrB8j.jpg)
[Path to .vbs file to show the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXlel.jpg)
[scheduled task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAe5M.jpg)
[more settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ksn9.jpg)
[even more settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zopk5.jpg)
[Last tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKoSQ.jpg)

Thanks, guys.

Comment: You must check "Run only when user is logged on" if you want to run interactive code.

Comment: Oh, but i have thap option clicked. Maybe i should have place some screen captures of all the settings. But thanks.

Comment: I ran your script via Task Scheduler, using the same settings, and the script popped up the MsgBox at the scheduled time. None of my paths have spaces, but I assume that's true for you as well because I see that you use underscore a lot. I can't see any problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway.